# Can someone explain this higher-order JavaScript function confusing syntax?

Tags: javascript

I am reading the book "Eloquent JavaScript".

In Chapter 5 he describes a particular higher-order function. It is called `noisy()` it is printed below...

```
function noisy(f) {
  return (...args) => {
   console.log("calling with", args);
   let result = f(...args);
   console.log("called with", args, ", returned", result);
   return result;
 };
}
```

Here is the part that is confusing me. He calls the function `noisy` as follows...

```
noisy(Math.min)(3,2,1);
```

I do not understand why the function is called that way. Why isn't it called like this...

```
noisy(Math.Min(3,2,1))
```

Edit: I see now what is going on. It was explained by Simone below.

```
noisy(Math.min)(3,2,1) is equivalent to (noisy(Math.min))(3,2,1).
```

Comment: `noisy` accepts a function and returns a function which calls the passed function.

Comment: I assume the purpose of `noisy` is to make some (well...) noise upon invoking the function (`f`) that is being passed to it. So, after you call `noisy(Math.min)` you get back a function that is then invoked using the `(3,2,1)` parameters. Essentially, decorating (or "proxying") the call to `f` for the purpose of logging to console before and after the actual invocation of `f`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to get the type of `noisy`, you'll get:

```
typeof noisy
>> "function"
```

Same thing if you ask for the type of `noisy(Math.min)`:

```
typeof noisy(Math.min)
>> "function"
```

If you want you can also store this function into a variable:

```
const noisyFunction = noisy(Math.min)
```

So that you can call it like a regular function:

```
noisyFunction(1,2,3)
```

`noisy(Math.min)(3,2,1)` is exactly the same, just written in a different, shorter way. The main point is, a higher-order function is just a function that returns a function.

Comment: Ok I get it. It could have been written like this (noisy(Math.min))(3,2,1) The precedence of the () operator causes it to be executed like I have written?

Comment: Yes, correct, but it won't work if written like in your second example, because they're not equivalent. `noisy(Math.min(3,2,1))` is a regular function call where `Math.min(3,2,1)` is the first and only argument.

Comment: Yes I understand that now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this.  I had the exact same question!

Answer (score 0):

`noisy(Math.min)` returns a function (see the return statement: `return (...args) => { ... }`).

`noisy(Math.min)(3,2,1);` just immediately calls that function.

You could also first assign the function to a variable and then call it like this:

```
let fnct = noisy(Math.min);
fnct(3,2,1);
```

---

You cannot call it like `noisy(Math.Min(3,2,1))`
as `Math.min(3,2,1)` returns a number but `noisy` expects a function reference to be passed (hence `Math.min` - note its missing the `()` as it's passing a reference to that function rather than the result of its execution).

Your call would break in line 4, i.e:

```
let result = f(...args);
```

as `f` is not a function in your case but rather the result of `Math.min(3,2,1) // = 1` .

Answer (score 0):

`noisy` returns a function that uses the parameter `f` as a callback function.

Here is an es5 version of the code (which needs a little more code to maintain functionality) to help you understand:

```js
function noisy(f) {
    return function () {
        var args = [];
        for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
            args[_i] = arguments[_i];
        }
        console.log("calling with", args);
        var result = f.apply(void 0, args);
        console.log("called with", args, ", returned", result);
        return result;
    };
}
//test
console.log(noisy(Math.min)(3, 2, 1));
```